# Comparing two data sets by using only their percentiles

Tags: quantiles

Lets say I have two data sets A,B (I have only access to percentile of two data sets and some more statistics like count , min , max). I'd like to compare how close these data sets are. I am failing to find a suitable metric for the same. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're after the two-sample [KS test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), that test will compare two distributions using their empirical distribution; this is if you're comparing 2 variables..;

Comment: That seems helpful, but I fail to see how the percentile data can be converted to empirical  distribution. Any example doing the same could be very helpful.

Comment: Which percentiles do you have?

Answer (score 1):

There is "Mountain" method of comparison of two or more dataset that gets the difference between distribution of these dataset and therefore how close they are. It uses the percentiles to compare dataset. You can use the [mountainplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mountainplot/index.html) package in R.

References

1. Jan S. Krouwer and Katherine L. Monti, A Simple, Graphical Method to Evaluate Laboratory Assays, Eur J Clin Chem Clin Biochem, 1995; 33:525-527, https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8547437/
2. Katherine L. Monti, Folded Empirical Distribution Function Curves-Mountain Plots, The American Statistician, Vol. 49, No. 4 (Nov., 1995), pp. 342-345, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684570

Comment: Any references to your answer could be helpful.

Comment: Therorically these references will be helpful: 
(1) Jan S. Krouwer and Katherine L. Monti, A Simple, Graphical Method to Evaluate Laboratory Assays, Eur J Clin Chem Clin Biochem, 1995; 33:525-527.  
(2) Katherine L. Monti, Folded Empirical Distribution Function Curves-Mountain Plots, The American Statistician, Vol. 49, No. 4 (Nov., 1995), pp. 342-345.
And package "mountainplot" in R software:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mountainplot/index.html

Comment: That information should be as an edit to your original answer, not in a comment!